# How do I use SASS the "normal way" with vue.js?

Tags: css, sass, vue.js, vuejs2

Up till now, I've used sass together with Grunt, the result being that I compile x .scss files into style.css.

I've only done one project in React and it's my first time working with Vue.js, so there a a few things I'm trying to understand.

If I want to include css styling in the same file as my Vue component, I can simply use

```
<style lang="sass">
   @import '_card.scss'
  // Custom CSS code here
</style>
```

From what I understand, Vue takes all the styling from all the .vue files and compiles it into style.css. But since I'm not sure, I ask this;

1. Are Vue components called in runtime and does that mean that specific parts of styling is compiled instead of loading all styling in one file?
2. I'm not a big fant of putting styling inside Vue component files. How can I load global styles? If I remember correctly, I had to load the css file in each React component and I don't see the point in this. I just want to load the style in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Vue Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Extracting-Component-CSS):
Extracting Component CSS

When using Single-File Components, the CSS inside components are injected dynamically as  tags via JavaScript. This has a small runtime cost, and if you are using server-side rendering it will cause a “flash of unstyled content”. Extracting the CSS across all components into the same file will avoid these issues, and also result in better CSS minification and caching.
Refer to the respective build tool documentations to see how it’s done:

- [Webpack + vue-loader](http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html) (**the vue-cli webpack template has this
  pre-configured**)
- [Browserify + vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify#css-extraction)
- [Rollup + rollup-plugin-vue](https://github.com/znck/rollup-plugin-vue#options)

So to answer your first question: "...specific parts of styling is compiled instead of loading all styling in one file?"

It depends on how your project is set up. If it was built with the webpack template, then yes it should combine those styles (though if you have them designated as scoped they will be prefixed for the component they originally came from)

For your second question:
To load the styles globally you can add the code you have already to App.vue

```
<style lang="sass">
   @import '_card.scss'
</style>
```